# Mocked HttpRequest loses the QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mocking, httprequest

I need to test an helper class which manage complex querystring.

I use this helper method to mock the `HttpContext`:

```
public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext(string url, string queryString)
{
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", url, queryString);
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
    var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

    var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                            new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
                                            HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                            SessionStateMode.InProc, false);
    SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(httpContext, sessionContainer);

    return httpContext;
}
```

The problem is that the `HttpRequest` loses the querystring:

```
HttpContext.Current = MockHelpers.FakeHttpContext("http://www.google.com/", "name=gdfgd");
```

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` is `"http://www.google.com/"` and not `"http://www.google.com/?name=gdfgd"`as expected.

If I debug I see that just after the HttpRequest constrctor the querystring is lost.

The workaround I'm using is to pass the url with querystring to the HttpRequest constructor:

```
HttpContext.Current = MockHelpers.FakeHttpContext("http://www.google.com/?name=gdfgd","");
```

Comment: I don't know enough about this, but I did copy your code and run it.  You are right about the querystring not showing up in the url, but it is not completely gone from the `HttpContext` as the `QueryString` property still has it.  I don't know what is expected behavior though.

Comment: @Halvard thanks, your comment has pointed me to the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Halvard's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704059/mocked-httprequest-loses-the-querystring#comment29273240_19704059) I had the clue to find the answer:

[HttpRequest constructor parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httprequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are disconnected between them.

The url parameter is used to create the `HttpRequest.Url` and the queryString is used for `HttpRequest.QueryString` property: **they are detached**

To have a consistent HttpRequest with an url with querystring you have to:

```
var httpRequest = new HttpRequest
      ("", "http://www.google.com/?name=gdfgd", "name=gdfgd");
```

Otherwise you'll have either the Url or the QueryString property not correctly loaded.

There is my updated Mock Helpers method:

```
public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext(string url)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, uri.ToString(), uri.Query.TrimStart('?'));
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
    var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

    var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                            new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
                                            HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                            SessionStateMode.InProc, false);
    SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(httpContext, sessionContainer);

    return httpContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri uriFull = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
```

Comment: I need to mock the httpContext!