# How do I get hold of the current HttpContextBase in an AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I need to get hold of the current `HttpContextBase` in an ASP.NET WEB API `AuthorizeAttribute`.

How do I get that from the `HttpActionContext` parameter in the overridden IsAuthorized()?

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
  // need to call code that requires the current Controllers HttpContextBase
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `HttpContext.Current`?

Comment: Nope. Needs to be TDD-able.

Comment: HttpContext isn't part of Web API, what is the actual information you are looking for.

Comment: @DarrelMiller, can you please provide a reference that back that claim? I need to read custom request headers in my AuthorizeAttribute. Problem solved, see answer.

Comment: @Magnus Try running your Web API under self-host.  There will be no static HttpContext.  Request headers are on the request object which is a property of HttpActionContext.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not so keen on doing authorization in the Action filters, I prefer to do that in authorization filters. Action filters are executed later in the pipeline than Authorization filters are. Besides, this implementation is not intended for self-Hosting scenarios at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I ended up using the HttpContextFactory approach as described in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9624433/3584

```
public class HttpContextFactory
{
    private static HttpContextBase m_context;
    public static HttpContextBase Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_context != null)
                return m_context;

            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("HttpContext not available");

            return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        }
    }

    public static void SetCurrentContext(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        m_context = context;
    }
}
```

I replaced all code that needed the current HttpContext with:

```
HttpContextFactory.Current...
```

In my unit tests, I do:

```
HttpContextFactory.SetCurrentContext(GetMockedHttpContext());
```

The mocked context:

```
private HttpContextBase GetMockedHttpContext()
{
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
    var user = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
    var identity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
    var urlHelper = new Mock<UrlHelper>();

    var routes = new RouteCollection();
    MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);
    var requestContext = new Mock<RequestContext>();
    requestContext.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(context.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(user.Object);
    user.Setup(ctx => ctx.Identity).Returns(identity.Object);
    identity.Setup(id => id.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
    identity.Setup(id => id.Name).Returns("test");
    request.Setup(req => req.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
    request.Setup(req => req.RequestContext).Returns(requestContext.Object);
    requestContext.Setup(x => x.RouteData).Returns(new RouteData());
    request.SetupGet(req => req.Headers).Returns(new NameValueCollection());

    return context.Object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use: `new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontextwrapper?view=netframework-4.8