# Pass login credentials and some session values from Controller to BL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having separate projects for  *view* and  *Business Logic*. 
Now I want to pass the Login credentials and some *session values* to the BL project. I know I can you ***Httpcontext.Current*** but I think it is not possible to unit test the code.

Is there any way to access the session and HttpcontextBase from BL project ?

Comment: When you want to pass the data from the client to server your able to pass through only request

Comment: you can access HttpContext by referencing it in your BL library

Comment: Kindly reference your BL project to your MVC project. Once referenced, In your method Login (ActionResult), used the passed parameter such username and password, and used that in your BL.
/* public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
      //your BL
      BusinessLogic.MethodName(username, password, other objects);

} */

Comment: you can unit test HttpContext: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624242/setting-httpcontext-current-session-in-a-unit-test

Comment: @persianDeveloper Yes , but  how can I unit test it ?

Comment: you can read @MikeDebela `s comment.

Comment: You can access the objects, but you shouldnt! just get the actual data out of the session etc as strings or whatever and pass these into your BL layer