# NSubstitute mock HttpActionDescriptor with ActionName

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I am writing some tests for an **AuthorizeAttribute** class I wrote for my Web API Controllers.  I am trying to mock up everything I need to be able to set the following vars within my class *AuthorizeAttributeTotalAccess*:

1. actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
2. controllerName = filterContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
3. claimsPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

**NOTE**:  *I am not married to HttpContext.Current and if there is another Context thaat will always have it, let me know.*

My Test, so far, looks like:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using BI.Security.Library.Authorization;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NSubstitute;


namespace AppTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class AttributeAuthorize
    {
        private AuthorizeAttributeTotalAccess _filter;
        private HttpActionContext _actionContext;
        private IPrincipal _originalPrincipal;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            var attributes = new Collection<AllowAnonymousAttribute>();

            var controllerDescriptor = Substitute.For<HttpControllerDescriptor>();
            controllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Returns(attributes);
            controllerDescriptor.ControllerName = "Template";

            var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext
            {
                Request = new HttpRequestMessage(),
                ControllerDescriptor = controllerDescriptor
            };

            // HOW DO I SET ACTIONNAME HERE???
            var actionDescriptor = Substitute.For<HttpActionDescriptor>();
            actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Returns(attributes);

            _actionContext = new HttpActionContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

            _originalPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            _filter = new AuthorizeAttributeTotalAccess();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = _originalPrincipal;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Returns_unauthorized_response_if_user_is_not_authenticated()
        {
            _filter.OnAuthorization(_actionContext);

            Assert.IsNotNull(_actionContext.Response);
            Assert.AreSame(_actionContext.Response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Returns_unauthorized_response_if_user_is_authenticated_but_not_in_system_roles()
        {
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = GetTestUser("admin");

            _filter.OnAuthorization(_actionContext);

            Assert.AreSame(_actionContext.Response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Short_circuits_request_if_user_is_authenticated_and_in_system_roles()
        {
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = GetTestUser("admin", "ApiWriteUser");

            _filter.OnAuthorization(_actionContext);

            Assert.IsNull(_actionContext.Response);
        }

        private IPrincipal GetTestUser(params string[] roles)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test User")}, "password");
            roles.ToList().ForEach(a => identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, a)));


            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            _actionContext.RequestContext.Principal = claimsPrincipal;

            return claimsPrincipal;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Again, how do I:

1. Set the **ActionName** so it is available in the class to be tested?
2. Set the **HttpContext.Current** so I can see the User?

Comment: For what it's worth, rather than using `HttpContext.Current.User` I would instead use `_actionContext.RequestContext.Principal`. This is easier to fake.

Comment: @vcsjones, how do you fake _actionContext.RequestContext.Principal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Set the ActionName so it is available in the class to be tested?

I'm not quite an expert on NSubstitute (read: I've never used it), but since your `HttpActionDescriptor` is a stub / mock, you should be able to stub the return value:

```
actionDescriptor.ActionName.Return("BLAH");
```

According to [NSubstitute's documentation](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/set-return-value/#for_properties), that's how you do a return value of a property.

> Set the HttpContext.Current so I can see the User?

[`HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) has a setter, so you should be able to set it to a fake context. [Other Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9624433/492405) demonstrate how to do this.

Comment: I missed that in the docs.  I'm brand new to NSubstitute.  Thanks vcsjones!