# Mock a controller which has a read-only property dependent on Httpcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

Using MOQ to mock ASP.Net MVC controller, I follow this approach:

```
var fakeHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

fakeHttpContext.Setup(t => t.User).Returns(genericPrincipal);

var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();

var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext.Setup(t => t.HttpContext)
    .Returns(fakeHttpContext.Object);

var controller = InitMyontrollerConstroctor(controllerContext);
```

And Here is how I initialize mycontroller:

```
var controller = new MyController(IService service)
{
    ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object,
};

return controller;
```

But a read-only property exist inside of `MyController`, which depends on `HttpContext`:

```
private static readonly string ServerPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/content/");

public ProfileController(IService service)
{

}
```

When I try to initialize my controller, it throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Not error. It is because `HttpContext` is *null*.

So, How can I supply `HttpContext` to my controller, without using as a parameter of the constructor.

Comment: Do not couple your code to static `HttpContext`. That is only available at run time and is provided by IIS. Create a service to encapsulate that and inject it into the controller as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get fake path for HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath which is assigned to protected object inside method unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805765/how-do-i-get-fake-path-for-httpcontext-current-server-mappath-which-is-assigned)