# Session null in unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, session, httpcontext

I am trying to write some unit tests for fairly basic controller actions, in which I set Session["User"]. When I run the test, it is failing at this point with a null reference exception. Not entirely sure how to get round this.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            Session["User"] = Id;

            if (Id != 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home", new { Id});
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Register", "Home", new { Id});
        }
```

Test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void NewUser_ShouldGoToRegister()
        {
            var controller = new HomeController();

            HttpContext.Current = FakeHttpContext();

            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("User", "0");

            var result = controller.Index(0) as ViewResult;

            Assert.AreEqual("Register", result.ViewName);
        }


        public HttpContext FakeHttpContext()
        {
            var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", "");

            var httpResponce = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());

            var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponce);
            var sessionContainer =
                new HttpSessionStateContainer("id",
                                               new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                               new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(),
                                               10,
                                               true,
                                               HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                               SessionStateMode.InProc,
                                               false);
            httpContext.Items["AspSession"] =
                typeof(HttpSessionState)
                .GetConstructor(
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                    null,
                                    CallingConventions.Standard,
                                    new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) },
                                    null)
                .Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });


            HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
        }
```

Comment: You need to read about mocking web objects such as HttpContext, HttpRequest etc. Basically read about unit testing controller code from start.

Comment: I've got a [TestInitialize] method that sets up stuff like that

Comment: How would we know that you have done that thing and what mistake you have made there? Please share the code.

Comment: Very sorry. I updated the code to include that. Meant to do that originally

Answer (score 1):

You can use some mocking tool like `MOQ` for mocking, to create fake `HttpContext` you can try like following code.

```
[TestMethod]
public void NewUser_ShouldGoToRegister()
{
    var controller = new HomeController();
    HttpContext.Current = FakeHttpContext();
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("User", 1);
    var result = controller.Index(0) as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual("Register", result.ViewName);
}
```

Your `FakeHttpContext` method should look like following code.

```
        //Creating a Fake HTTP Context           
        // This is used for testing methods using Session Variables.
        private HttpContext FakeHttpContext()
        {
            var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://somethig.com/", "");
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            var httpResponce = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
            var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponce);

            var sessionContainer = 
                new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                                    new HttpStaticObjectsCollection()
                                                    , 10,
                                                    true,
                                                    HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                                    SessionStateMode.InProc, false);

            httpContext.Items["AspSession"] = 
                typeof(HttpSessionState).GetConstructor(
                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                        null, CallingConventions.Standard,
                                        new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) },
                                        null)
                                .Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });

            return httpContext;
        }
```

Comment: I've just tried using this method and I still get a null session when i debug into it. Any ideas?

Comment: Still null. It's definitely set's up the session in the test but when it goes through the the controller it's null

Comment: did you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624242/setting-httpcontext-current-session-in-a-unit-test

Comment: I have looked at that question but no success :/

Comment: this is strange, it always worked for me. Can you check the session key, you are trying to access the same which you are adding?

Comment: Sorry if i sound dumb but what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, what you are setting in session using a key, are you using same key while getting it from session.

Comment: Yes that's all the same i think

Comment: I have no idea what is going on. I've checked everything and it all looks correct but once I go into that controller, suddent HttpContect.Current doesn't exist but HttpContext.Session does and it's null. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you have difficulties with this, this idea might help you overthinking it. Sometimes it's a good idea to create another layer of access to `Session`.

A simplified way would be to never directly access "Session", but rather have it wrapped into methods like this:

```
protected virtual string ReadFromSession(string key)
{
    return Session[key];
}

protected virtual void StoreInSession(string key, string value)
{
    Session[key] = value;
}
```

Everywhere in your Controller, you just use these methods instead of directly accessing `Session`. Easy enough.

Now the trick is that with Unit Test, you can override the Controller which you test:

```
public class MyControllerForTesting : MyController
{
    private readonly IDictionary session;

    public MyControllerForTesting(IDictionary session) : base()
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    protected override string ReadFromSession(string key)
    {
        return this.session[key];
    }

    protected override void StoreInSession(string key, string value)
    {
        this.session[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Now this might not work immediately as I didn't really test it but you get the Idea. Your unit tests work and you even can inspect the Dictionary if the values were set correctly etc.